# Is there a way to block all TOR traffic incident on my public servers?

Tags: network, tor

I don't want any connections coming from a tor network to be accepted by my servers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [I want to ban the Tor network from my service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq-abuse.html.en#Bans) from the official Tor documentation.

The Tor project provides [a list with IPs](https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py) of all the exit nodes that can access your service, use query string parameters to tell it the IP and port of your service, example : https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=8.8.8.8&port=443.

You can then loop through the results, split them each newline, ignore lines starting with "#" and finally adding a `-J DROP` IPtables action to each one of them or using an [IPset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) which would give you better performance with such a large number of hosts, something like this should do the trick :

```
ipset -N tor iphash # create a new set named "tor"

# get the list, don't forget to put your service's IP in the query string
curl -s https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=8.8.8.8 | sed '/^#/d' | while read IP
do
  # add each IP address to the set, silencing the warnings for IPs that have already been added
  ipset -q -A tor $IP
done

iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set tor src -j DROP # block any IP in this set in IPtables
```

*[(source)](http://mikhailian.mova.org/node/194)*

They also provide a [DNS based list](https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en) but it's still in experimental stage so I suggest you stick with the first option, it's also easier to work with.

Comment: Any DNS-based (or hash-based) solution is going to need routine updating.  If you're okay with that, then carry on.  Otherwise, you need a Layer 7 aware firewall OR, you could hack something together like this bloke: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/3120-how-i-stopped-tor-traffic-in-our-network